# can't boot into windows, was removed from grub. somehow

Tags: debian, filesystems, windows

So. I installed Debian on my asus laptop, resized the windows partition, and installed Debian 11(stable). windows was automatically add to grub and everything was good. I apt update && apt upgrade, and when I went to reboot, windows boot was gone. All the partitions look like they're still there.

1. Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 116.48 GiB, 125069950976 bytes, 244277248 sectors
2. Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
3. Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
4. I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
5. Disklabel type: gpt
6. Disk identifier: 32BD2B1E-DBD1-4782-93F4-A9EA7A7AC78E

- Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
- /dev/mmcblk0p1 157390848 158439423   1048576  512M EFI System
- /dev/mmcblk0p2    534528    567295     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
- /dev/mmcblk0p3    567296 157388804 156821509 74.8G Microsoft basic data
- /dev/mmcblk0p4 158439424 240431103  81991680 39.1G Linux filesystem
- /dev/mmcblk0p5 242432000 243865599   1433600  700M BIOS boot
- /dev/mmcblk0p6 243865600 244275199    409600  200M Windows recovery environment
- /dev/mmcblk0p7 240431104 242431999   2000896  977M Linux swap

but I can't seem to get windows to boot. It's not an option in the bios either. shows 2 debian options, which is weird. anyways, I've looked all over qnd haven't found anything that would even pointme in the right direction. please helpo. thanks.

Comment: You should always have a Windows boot option in UEFI boot menu. But you show both ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot and bios_grub (BIOS boot) for BIOS boot on gpt drive. Those are not compatible. All systems should be UEFI. Grub also removing os-prober for security reason for now. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GDRKrrs3 and I'm working on finding the ppa for boot-repair.

Comment: I dunno if you got my last post, but here, https://pastebin.com/GDRKrrs3. IT's set to burn in an hour. lemme know if you can't see it, plus I'mhaving mad issues installed boot-repair. I'm thinking it because its designed for unbuntu? I dunno. Imma keep trying,

Comment: I cannot look at paste. Never seen the burn after looking once. We all are volunteers and others should also look at it and see something I miss.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PG9U4ML5

Comment: Report is missing almost all of its normal data? I have seen it work with Debian before and it should. It also checks to make sure you have the typical Linux tools in case your version does not have it, and then will ask to install that.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent version of Grub in debian the defaults were changed.

By default, grub's setup scripts no longer scan for other OSen.

This behaviour was documented at https://wiki.debian.org/Grub :

> **When I upgraded from GRUB to GRUB2 I lost an entry to XP/WP7 , how can
> I recover the menu entry to boot there?**
>
> You have to install os-prober, make sure its enabled in GRUB2 configuration and sync GRUB2.
>
> `apt-get install os-prober`
>
> Then edit /etc/default/grub and make sure you have a line like
>
> `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`

I had the same issue while updating a legacy system, and this worked for me.

Comment: so I tried that and nothing changed.  I've been playing with different dist of linux starting with 18 floppys to install redhat and I deleted the windows partition on my parents $1500 computer, so I thought of myself as somewhat knowledgeable.. guess not. here's a boot repair report. anyways, please help.  Pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/D3ysh4DzYF

Comment: I don't have a ubuntu.com login and can't view that pastebin. Include the actual text in an edit of the actual question.

Comment: it's way to much to post here. try this.  https://pastebin.com/h76nqwTS